# JSP compilation failing after installing ear

Tags: jsp, websphere, wcs

Using WAS console I removed an application and re-installed it. Since after that I am getting below error.

```
Error Page Exception
```

SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Original Exception:

Error Message: JSPG0049E: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp failed to compile : JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 222 in the statically included file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/include/JSTLEnvironmentSetup.jspf JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war_ibmjsp\EliteStorefrontAssetStore\UserArea\AccountSection\LogonSubsection_LogonSetup.java : 460 : The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String, int) JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 223 in the statically included file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/include/JSTLEnvironmentSetup.jspf JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war_ibmjsp\EliteStorefrontAssetStore\UserArea\AccountSection\LogonSubsection_LogonSetup.java : 461 : The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String, int) 
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp
Error Stack: 
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0049E: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp failed to compile :

```
 JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 222 in the statically included file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/include/JSTLEnvironmentSetup.jspf 
 JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp 

 D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war\_ibmjsp\EliteStorefrontAssetStore\UserArea\AccountSection\LogonSubsection\_LogonSetup.java : 460 : The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String, int) 

 JSPG0225E: An error occurred at line: 223 in the statically included file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/include/JSTLEnvironmentSetup.jspf 
 JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /EliteStorefrontAssetStore/UserArea/AccountSection/LogonSubsection/LogonSetup.jsp 

 D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war\_ibmjsp\EliteStorefrontAssetStore\UserArea\AccountSection\LogonSubsection\_LogonSetup.java : 461 : The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String, int) 

 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:612) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:479) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:337) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:153) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:372) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.processRequest(ECActionServlet.java:225) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.doGet(ECActionServlet.java:166) 
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718) 
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.campaigns.filter.CampaignsFilter.doFilter(CampaignsFilter.java:148) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter.doFilter(LikeMindsFilter.java:183) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter$1.run(CacheFilter.java:377) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:508) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(RuntimeServletFilter.java:724) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.access$0(RuntimeServletFilter.java:534) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter$1.run(RuntimeServletFilter.java:475) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(RuntimeServletFilter.java:500) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83) 
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)
```

Error Page Exception:

Error Message: JSPG0049E: /error.jsp failed to compile : JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 45 in the file: /error.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /error.jsp D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war_ibmjsp_error.java : 120 : The method setValue(Object) in the type OutTag is not applicable for the arguments (int) JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 56 in the file: /error.jsp JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /error.jsp D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war_ibmjsp_error.java : 140 : The method setValue(Object) in the type OutTag is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: /error.jsp
Error Stack: 
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0049E: /error.jsp failed to compile :

```
 JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 45 in the file: /error.jsp 
 JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /error.jsp 

 D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war\_ibmjsp\_error.java : 120 : The method setValue(Object) in the type OutTag is not applicable for the arguments (int) 

 JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 56 in the file: /error.jsp 
 JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /error.jsp 

 D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\mistage\temp\WC_mistage_node\server1\WC_mistage\Stores.war\_ibmjsp\_error.java : 140 : The method setValue(Object) in the type OutTag is not applicable for the arguments (int) 

 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:612) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:479) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:337) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:153) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:372) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3369) 
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:255) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:372) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241) 
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.processRequest(ECActionServlet.java:225) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionServlet.doGet(ECActionServlet.java:166) 
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718) 
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250) 
 at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.campaigns.filter.CampaignsFilter.doFilter(CampaignsFilter.java:148) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter.doFilter(LikeMindsFilter.java:183) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter$1.run(CacheFilter.java:377) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:508) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilterAction(RuntimeServletFilter.java:724) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.access$0(RuntimeServletFilter.java:534) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter$1.run(RuntimeServletFilter.java:475) 
 at com.ibm.commerce.webcontroller.RuntimeServletFilter.doFilter(RuntimeServletFilter.java:500) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592) 
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305) 
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83) 
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)
```

Comment: `LogonSubsection_LogonSetup.java : 460 : The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)` seems like a problem in your code, take a look at that. If you have miltiple libraries of your project in the WAR, check if everything has the right version.

Comment: It would help if you can show us your code. Easier to see if there is something wrong there as the error message implies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is very old - but if someone else faces this error, one line of investigation is:

The root error seems to be this:

The method setAttribute(String, Object) in the type ServletRequest is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Looks like the JSP is passing a parameter of primitive type `(int)` when it expects an Object. Changing the code to pass `new Integer(int)` could solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more